# Difference between value of 'this' in client-side vs server-side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Writing a few nodejs test programs and am running into a few unexpected quirks. In the browser when I say `console.log(this);` and it is not in a function, it is the window.object. I know that nodejs has a global object but when I do console.log(this) I simply get an empty object. Then when I ask for the value of 'this' inside a function I created I get `undefined`. I expected to get a reference to the current function (myClass, in this case) What is going on here?

See my following nodejs program:

```
'use strict';
var log = console.log; 

log(this); //empty object

function myClass() {    
    log (this); //undefined 
    this.variable = 3; //exception, cannot set property 'test' of undefined
}

myClass();
```

Thanks

Comment: It actually is because of strict mode, in strict, `this` is not the global object by default. The spec says *A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object in strict mode* !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript

Comment: btw, i don't think that console log will work in browsers, as it has the wrong internal _this_...

Comment: `this` **never** (implicitly) refers to the function it is used in. Your exception is simply wrong.

Comment: @dandavis can you elaborate?

Comment: I also get `undefined` in the browser btw: http://jsfiddle.net/ow0ozmfc/.

Comment: should use var log = console.log.bind(console);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `node.js` behaves correctly here, because you're not constructing a class, just calling it's constructor without any `this` context. To create new instance of a class you should always use `new` operator:

```
new myClass();
```

The difference in behavior is caused by [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), because in strict mode, due to security reasons, `this` [is not referencing the global object by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is caused by this:

```
'use strict';
```

If you use that code in client-side you will have the same behaviour.

Comment: Very interesting, one thing I noticed was that the value of 'this' inside myClass still logged the window object. What's going on there?